# Why doesn't Ansible change the default MariaDB password?

Tags: ansible, mariadb

I have an Ubuntu VM. However, when I try to change the default password (Empty Password) for MariaDB via Ansible, it says that I don't have permission to do so. I can normally login to MariaDB using `sudo mysql -u root -p`.

I tried setting **become: yes**, but it didn't work.

Can you help me?

**playbook.yml**:

```
- hosts: vm-bd-01
  vars:   
     mysql_root_password: password  
  tasks:
  - name: Install MariaDB Server
    apt:
      pkg:
      - mariadb-server
      - python3-pymysql
      update_cache: yes
    become: yes
  - name: Change default MariaDB password
    become: yes
    mysql_user:  
      login_host: 'localhost'
      login_user: 'root'  
      login_password: ''
      name: 'root'
      password: '{{ mysql_root_password }}'
      state: present
```

**Error**:

```
TASK [Change default MariaDB password] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [IP]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_******** are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1698, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'\")"}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the playbook? Do you get an error, does it succeed but without making the expected changes, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting with no password, you need to connect over the mysql unix socket (`/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`) instead of over a TCP connection. Compare the behavior of:

```
root@ubuntu:~# mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 31
Server version: 10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Ubuntu 22.04

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> ^DBye
```

With:

```
root@ubuntu:~# mysql -h 127.0.0.1
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Rewrite your playbook to connect over the unix socket:

```
- hosts: vm-bd-01
  vars:
     mysql_root_password: password
  tasks:
  - name: Install MariaDB Server
    apt:
      pkg:
      - mariadb-server
      - python3-pymysql
      update_cache: yes
    become: yes
  - name: Change default MariaDB password
    become: yes
    mysql_user:
      login_unix_socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
      login_user: 'root'
      login_password: ''
      name: 'root'
      password: '{{ mysql_root_password }}'
      state: present
```

With this change, your playbook runs successfully for me:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Install MariaDB Server] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Change default MariaDB password] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And now a password is required:

```
root@ubuntu:~# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@ubuntu:~# mysql -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 35
Server version: 10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Ubuntu 22.04

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: I changed the setting as you suggested. I can now access MariaDB using  `sudo mysql -u root -p` or  `mysql -u root -p`. Thanks.

Comment: I am unclear on where things stand at the moment: the edits to your question suggest that you're still seeing an error? The playbook presented in this answer runs without errors, as written, on an Ubuntu 22.04 system.

Comment: It's working as I wanted. I edited the post and added the error to make it easier to understand what was going on. If I wanted to improve the idempotency of this block what could I do? If I've already run the playbook once and the password has already been changed what could I do to continue other tasks if they exist?

Comment: That's an other question. Comments are not for questions. Ask a new one. Thanks.